# Hammer.js: Swipe event not working on images

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, hammer.js

I'm using `hammer.js` for gesture functionality on my web application.  I have used it to swipe a video element and it works perfect as expected.  However, when I apply the following code to an image element it's not working.

```
App.Views.Photo = Backbone.View.extend({
template  : template('photoTemplate'),
className : 'photo',
parent    : null,

events: {
    'swipe' : 'swiped',
    // 'pan'    : 'dragged'
},
```

...

```
swiped: function(e) {

    this.remove();
    this.parent.newContent(this.model);
},
```

This exact same code is working for the video elements but not for the images. I also tried doing `e.gesture.preventDefault();` inside the swiped function but that didn't work either.  I'm testing the application on firefox at the moment.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

[EDIT]: I'm initializing the hammer code as follows

```
render: function() {

    $(this.el).attr('id', this.model.attributes._id);
    this.$el.html( this.template( this.model.toJSON() ) );

    this.$el.hammer();

    return this;
},
```

Comment: and where are you creating a hammer instance in that code..?

Comment: Sorry about that ... See edited answer above. And once again this exact same code is working for the video element but not the images

Comment: Wow, no one knows the solution or why this might be happening?

Comment: Viewed 65 times and not a soul knows how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, so after banging my head on this problem for weeks I finally got the answer.

in the `initialize` function I placed the following code

```
$('img').on('dragstart', function(event) { event.preventDefault(); });
```

So it looks like this

```
initialize: function(opts) {
    this.render();
    this.parent = opts.parent;

    $('img').on('dragstart', function(event) { event.preventDefault(); });
},
```

What this does is that it prevents the image from being dragged like default and that did the trick.

And now on `swipe` the image gets removed like I wanted.

[EDIT]
If you have multiple images on the page add `this` to the event like

```
this.$('img').on('dragstart', function(event) { event.preventDefault(); });
```

This will apply to all of the picture that are rendered with that view.

Comment: any idea why `<video>` elements doesn't have this issue..?

Comment: Nope. I think images have a default drag functionality and videos (video elements) don't.

Answer (score 5):

You can use:

```
<img draggable="false"...
```

Or in CSS like this (May not be supported by all browsers, esp IE)

```
pointer-events: none;
```